# "Ordered lists" and bi- vs. uni-directional relationships

Tags: neo4j, relationships

I'm a Neo4j newbie, just playing around in the browser modelling data for a project at the moment.

Here's my use case: A user can have a bunch of items. Each item is described by a storyline.

```
(:User)-[:OWNS]->(:Item)<-[:DESCRIBES]-(:Storyline)
```

No issues so far. However, the storyline needs to contain "cards", basically chapters of the story that need to be in order. So, my first thought was this.

```
(:Storyline)<-[:FOLLOWS]<-(a:Card)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(b:Card)
```

However, if we start at Card B, we now have to follow the path back to see what storyline/item the card belongs to. Seems inefficient. Would it be better to do this?

```
(a:Card {order: 0})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:Storyline)
(b:Card {order: 1})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:Storyline)
```

Or, might I even trash the Storyline and just have the following?

```
(:Card {order:0})-[:DESCRIBES]->(:Item)
```

Next, a user should be free to create a link to another storyline card belonging to his own or any other user's item.

```
(storyA:Card)-[:LINKS_TO]->(storyB:Card)
```

However, the owner of storyB may or may not want to link back to the first guy's story. I know you can ignore the direction of the relationship in a cypher query by doing:

```
(a)-[r]-(b)
```

But I read that explicitly creating bi-directional relationships is usually a bad idea. So if storyB wants to link back, how would you best represent this in the data model? Maybe another relationship type, like :LINKS_MUTUALLY or something, or a "mutual" boolean property on the :LINKS_TO relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you first issue, it's usually better to have relationships rather than properties in this case.

I'd throw in `FIRST` and `LAST` relationships, like in this [TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree), and model it as:

```
(a:Card)-[:DESCRIBES]->(i:Item)
(b:Card)-[:DESCRIBES]->(i:Item)
(c:Card)-[:DESCRIBES]->(i:Item)
(a:Card)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(b:Card)
(b:Card)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(c:Card)
(a:Card)<-[:FIRST_CARD]-(i:Item) //optional, for easy navigation
(c:Card)<-[:LAST_CARD]-(i:Item)  //optional, for easy navigation
```

As for bidirectional relationships, the only are a bad idea if a relationship in one direction *implies* the other one. In your case, this is not the case, so creating `(storyA:Card)-[:LINKS_TO]->(storyB:Card)` and `(storyA:Card)<-[:LINKS_TO]-(storyB:Card)` is perfectly fine, since each relationship is there for a different reason.